# make a form that show images from a folder

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I have to build a form that shows images. Example, I need to show all students images from class a or class b and etc. I need it to automatically base on the names in the table and query. So if I open form "class a" it will fill automatically.

I need it to be like:

```
                           [] [] [] [] [] 
                           [] [] [] [] []
                           [] [] [] [] []

                             and so on
```

(sorry it didn't let me upload image)

Answer (score 0):

The images are named same as the value in table? Use an Image control and set ControlSource property to the image file path concatenated to field. Example:

`="C:\folderpath\" & [fieldname] & ".jpg"`

However, arranging in columns as you show will likely not be practical on form. Build a report and use Column formatting.